# Schemacrawler throws error for SQL Server

Tags: database, schema, schemacrawler

When trying to draw a schema diagram, i am not able to execute the below command

```
sc -host=hostname -database=dw -schemas=dw\..* -infolevel=standard -routines= -infolevel=maximum -tabletypes=TABLE -grepcolumns=.*\.Accountkey -only-matching -command=graph -outputformat=pdf
```

The error thrown is 'unrecognized command'. I have done this before but am not sure what I am doing wrong this time. Graphviz was already installed.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which version of SchemaCrawler you are using, and the actual error text? I believe that your command prompt is giving you that error message.

Comment: Hi Sualeh. I have version 14.08.01. I downloaded latest from github. I am trying to pull up a db diagram using schemacrawler. It has worked perfectly before . Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doung. No compilation is needed. Please email me directly.

Comment: ...les\db-specific-query>"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -classpath ../../_schemacrawler/lib/*;lib/* schemacrawler.Main -server=MSSQLServer -database=dw  -infolevel=standard -command=dw.tables %*

Comment: Hi.. again.. i was playing around the src files instead of just downloading the main zip file .. I am able to run schemacrawler, but it gives a new error with above command Unsupported server, MSSQLServer
Re-run SchemaCrawler with the
-?
option for help